# hg merge says outstanding uncommitted changes; hg commit says nothing changed -- how to exit the loop?

Tags: mercurial

The problem here is that hg' workflow apparently leads in a circle:

1. hg pull, get another head
2. hg merge, get warned of outstanding
   uncommitted changes
3. hg commit -m "pre merge commit", get message
   saying nothing changed
4. go to 2 hg status, see output like the
   following:

   ```
   ! #foo.py#
   ? junk.out
   ? junk2.out
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If foo.py is in your list of .hg-ignore'd files try specifying it explicity on the command line when you commit.

e.g.

```
hg commit -m "commit message" ./#foo.py
```

---

edit: looking more closely at your error: the file has been deleted (! in the status list), but hg hasn't tracked the deletion. You need to tell hg about the deletion using:

```
hg rm -A ./foo.py
```

The `-A / --after` means record the removal after it actually occured

Comment: I have the problem that merge is canceled but status doesn't show any changes. And I am pretty sure that I didn't change anything after commit. I just commited and tried to push. Then realized that a fellow pushed his code and wanted to merge it... It seems to be broken. Maybe fastest solution is a fresh clone...

Comment: Fresh clone "solved" the problem. Until today when fellow pushed something. The only local changes I had where successfully commited. Then I wanted to push and realized that I had to merge with local. "Uncommited local changes are detected". Crap. Commit, shelve and discard don't do anything. They can't - there's nothing... I would only recommend Mercurial to my enemies. It's just annoying.